# ¿Cómo mostrar los resultados de una subconsulta sql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Estoy haciendo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT
  items_id,
  titulo,
  COUNT(titulo)*100 / (
    SELECT
      COUNT(titulo)
    FROM `meli_ordenes` as B
    WHERE
      A.items_id = B.items_id AND
      siteid='$pais'
  ) AS porcentaje
FROM `ordenes` as A
WHERE
  amount=0.00 AND
  siteid='$pais'
GROUP BY items_id
```

Lo que necesito es obtener también en los resultados de la consulta el total de la subconsulta, es decir el divisor.

Como podría hacer esto?. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entiendo que la forma más cómoda es plantear una subconsulta. Algo así:

```
SELECT  T.items_id,
  T.titulo,
  T.Cantidad1 * 100 / T.Cantidad2 AS 'porcentaje',
  T.Cantidad2
FROM
  ( SELECT
     items_id,
     titulo, 
     COUNT(titulo) as 'Cantidad1',
     ( SELECT
        COUNT(titulo)
        FROM `meli_ordenes` as B
        WHERE
          A.items_id = B.items_id AND
          siteid='$pais'
      ) as 'Cantidad2'
    FROM `ordenes` as A
    WHERE
      amount=0.00 AND
      siteid = '$pais'
    GROUP BY items_id
  ) T
```

De esta forma, materializas la columna que sale de la subconsulta sobre `meli_ordenes` y la puedes usar tanto para el porcentaje como para mostrarla también.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta!, me devuelve este comentario: #1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca '(SELECT
        COUNT(titulo)
        FROM `meli_ordenes` as B
        WHERE
' en la linea 10

Comment: Faltaba una coma luego de `Cantidad1` revisa si era eso. Saludos